Accessing Dereferenced pointer exception with nested classes
I am programming something in C++, and while dealing with child classes that contain a pointer to parent classes, I ran into a de-referenced pointer exception. The simplified code is this:
class top {
public:
    int val = 0;
    class mid {
    public:
        top* parent;
        class low {
        public:
            mid* parent = nullptr;
            void addToVal() {
                parent->parent->val += 1;
            }
            low(mid* Parent) {
                parent = Parent;
            }
            low() {}
        };
        low child;
        mid(top* Parent) {
            parent = Parent;
            child = low(this);
        }
    };
    mid::low child;
    top() {
        child = (mid(this)).child;
    };
};
int main()
{
    top t = top();
    t.child.addToVal();
}

But the tl;dr of that code is, you have three classes, the top class tries to access the child of the mid class, then the low class tries to access a value in the top class. I know that the error comes from these two lines: mid::low child; and child =(mid(this)).child; But I don't know why this pointer becomes dereferenced after doing this, as the pointers to the parents are defined when the mid constructor is called, as the mid constructor also calls the low constructor.
Does anyone know what is happening here when the child is created?

The temporary object was just so I could write the PPR  in less lines, that's not included in my real code. And just to make sure, I  checked, and changing that to a variable does not change result. (EDIT: I was wrong about the previous statement, the positioning of my variable declaration mattered, so what I thought was a permanent variable was actually temporary). And yes, this class structure is necessary unless I want to write 153 switch case statements(although it is weird I'll admit).

Running this through GCC with -fsanitize=address yields:
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address 0x79bea1c00060 at pc 0x0000004012be bp 0x7ffce7648020 sp 0x7ffce7648018
READ of size 8 at 0x79bea1c00060 thread T0
    #0 0x4012bd in top::mid::low::addToVal() /app/example.cpp:11
    #1 0x40120f in main /app/example.cpp:31
    #2 0x79bea3a29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 962015aa9d133c6cbcfb31ec300596d7f44d3348)
    #3 0x79bea3a29e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: 962015aa9d133c6cbcfb31ec300596d7f44d3348)
    #4 0x4010c4 in _start (/app/output.s+0x4010c4) (BuildId: 52657344baa840d03bd8657b741b84c6bfb25e30)

Address 0x79bea1c00060 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 32 in frame
    #0 0x401541 in top::top() /app/example.cpp:25

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 48) '<unknown>' <== Memory access at offset 32 is inside this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return /app/example.cpp:11 in top::mid::low::addToVal()

The reason for the problem is that mid(this) is a temporary. When it's constructed, it passes a pointer to itself into low, and that pointer is required to access the top instance via parent->parent.
So, after you copy mid(this).child into top::child, the temporary mid value is destroyed which leaves you with a dangling pointer stored in child.parent. Attempting child.addToVal() then tries to dereference this dangling pointer, which results in undefined behavior.
You should rethink your design. If low requires a pointer to top and mid is typically temporary, then just store it directly instead of storing mid:
class low {
public:
    top* parent = nullptr;
    void addToVal() {
        parent->val += 1;
    }
    low(mid* Parent) {
        parent = Parent->parent;
    }
    low() {}
};

Alternatively, come up with a less convoluted design!

Thank you! The fact that the child object was temporary was something that I thought wasn't true in my original code, but I realized I put my variable declaration INSIDE the constructor and not OUTSIDE, so it was being destroyed upon use.

It's interest question about several class need to access their's friend of the friends each others.
I try to write simulate code.
I am not sure if it cause the same problems.
Maybe someone can review it and provide some suggestions.
xx.h :
#ifndef _XX_H_
#define _XX_H_

#include <new>
#include<iostream>

class low;
class mid;
//class top;

class top {
public:
    friend class mid;
    friend class low;
    mid *TopChild=nullptr;
    low *TopGrandson=nullptr;
    int val ;
    top() ;
};

class mid {
public:
    friend class top;
    friend class low;
    top* MidParent=nullptr;
    low* MidChild=nullptr;
    mid(top* P) ;
};

class low {
public:
    friend class mid;
    friend class top;
    //mid* LowParent = nullptr;
    mid* LowParent=nullptr;
    void addToVal() ;
    low(mid* P) ;
    low() ;
};


#endif  // #ifndef _XX_H_

xx.cpp :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <new>
#include <ostream>
#include "x.h"

using namespace std;

//class top {
    top::top() {
        val = 30;
        cout << "top::top this =" << this << endl;
        cout << "top::top TopChild =" << TopChild << endl;
        if (!TopChild)
          TopChild = new mid(this);
        cout << "top::top TopChild =" << TopChild << endl;
        cout << "top::top TopGrandson =" << TopGrandson << endl;
        if (!TopGrandson)
          cout << "*TopChild->MidChild=" << TopChild->MidChild << endl;
          if (TopChild->MidChild) {
            TopGrandson = TopChild->MidChild;
          } else {
            TopGrandson = new low(TopChild);
          }
        cout << "top::top TopGrandson =" << TopGrandson << endl;
    };
//};

//class mid {
    mid::mid(top* P) {
        cout << "  mid::mid(P): this=" << this << ", P=" << P << endl;
        cout << "  mid::mid(P): MidParent =" << MidParent << endl;
        MidParent = P;
        cout << "  mid::mid(P): MidParent =" << MidParent << endl;
        cout << "  mid::mid(P): MidChild =" << MidChild << endl;
        if (!MidChild)
          MidChild = new low(this);
        cout << "  mid::mid(P): MidChild =" << MidChild << endl;
    }
//};

//class low {
    void low::addToVal() {
        if (!LowParent) cout << ":: low::addToVal(): LowParent==" << LowParent << endl;
        if (!(LowParent->MidParent)) cout << "::: low::addToVal(): LowParent->MidParent==" << LowParent->MidParent << endl;
        cout << "low(" << this << ")::addToVal: " << LowParent->MidParent->val ;
        LowParent->MidParent->val += 1;
        cout << " --> " << LowParent->MidParent->val << endl;
    }
    low::low(mid* P) {
        cout << "    low::low(*P): this=" << this << ", P=" << P << endl;
        cout << "    low::low(*P): LowParent=" << LowParent << endl;
        LowParent = P;
        cout << "    low::low(*P): LowParent=" << LowParent << endl;
    }
    low::low() {
        cout << "    low::low(): this=" << this << endl;
        cout << "    low::low(): LowParent=" << LowParent << endl;
        LowParent = nullptr;
        cout << "    low::low(): LowParent=" << LowParent << endl;
    }
//};


int main()
{
    top t = top();
    //t.child.addToVal();
    t.TopGrandson->addToVal();
}

result:
top::top this =0x66fe94
top::top TopChild =0
  mid::mid(P): this=0x1029a38, P=0x66fe94
  mid::mid(P): MidParent =0
  mid::mid(P): MidParent =0x66fe94
  mid::mid(P): MidChild =0
    low::low(*P): this=0x1029a48, P=0x1029a38
    low::low(*P): LowParent=0
    low::low(*P): LowParent=0x1029a38
  mid::mid(P): MidChild =0x1029a48
top::top TopChild =0x1029a38
top::top TopGrandson =0
*TopChild->MidChild=0x1029a48
top::top TopGrandson =0x1029a48
low(0x1029a48)::addToVal: 30 --> 31

